# How to build a Keil Uvision project via system() function, when the system() function is used in Qt creator?

Tags: c++, qt, qmake, keil

I am able to build my project via the command prompt using:

```
UV4 -b project_name.uvproj
```

However, trying to execute the same with the `system()` function has been giving an error as shown below even after the path was specified:

```
The system cannot find the specified path
```

Also, if I use `system()` multiple times one after the other, do they execute successively in the command processor or every time `system()` is used, is it a separate instance altogether?

Comment: Have you tried to call `UV4-b` with full path? Looks like `system` is a synchronous function.